# Codeigniter 4 Subquery whereIn function BaseBuilder not working

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-4

I have tried the Codeigniter 4 subquery several ways and I am now trying a method from post stackoverflow.com/questions/66795533/writing-sql-subquery-with-ci4-active-record but not working. Receiving the below error. I tried to change the type as specified below but no good.

> TypeError
> App\Models\Mbox\Mbox_model::App\Models\Mbox{closure}(): Argument #1 ($subqueryBuilder) must be of type App\Models\Mbox\BaseBuilder,

Below is my model and query.

```
namespace App\Models\Mbox;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class Mbox_model extends Model
{
public function get_messages($uid,$box)
{
    $db = \Config\Database::connect();

    $builder = $db->table('messages');//->fromSubquery($subquery, 'mc');

    $builder->select('messages.*,users.*,conversations.created_on,conversations.fromuser,
                      conversations.read, conversations.message')
            ->join('conversations', 'conversations.mid = messages.mid')
            ->join('users', 'users.id = conversations.fromuser')
            ->where('messages.owner', $uid)
            ->where('mailbox', $box)
            ->whereIn('conversations.cid', function (BaseBuilder $subqueryBuilder) 
                                                     {
                                                        return $subqueryBuilder->selectMax('mc.cid')
                                                                               ->from('conversations mc')
                                                                               ->join('messages', 'messages.owner = mc.touser')
                                                                               ->where('messages.owner',$uid)
                                                                               ->where('messages.mailbox', $box)
                                                                               ->groupBy('mc.fromuser');
                                                    })->orderBy('created_on', 'DESC');
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. You must include use CodeIgniter\Database\BaseBuilder;

I also had to add use the anonymous function as described in a Codeigniter forum to pass parameters and now the query looks good.

```
$db = \Config\Database::connect();

    $builder = $db->table('messages');

    $builder->select('messages.*,users.*,conversations.created_on,conversations.fromuser,
                      conversations.read, conversations.message')
            ->join('conversations', 'conversations.mid = messages.mid')
            ->join('users', 'users.id = conversations.fromuser')
            ->whereIn('conversations.cid', function (BaseBuilder $subqueryBuilder) use ($uid,$box)
                                                     {
                                                        return $subqueryBuilder->selectMax('mc.cid')
                                                                               ->from('conversations mc')
                                                                               ->join('messages', 'messages.owner = mc.touser')
                                                                               ->where('messages.owner', $uid)
                                                                               ->where('messages.mailbox', $box)
                                                                               ->groupBy('mc.fromuser');
                                                    })
            ->where('messages.owner', $uid)
            ->where('mailbox', $box)
            ->orderBy('created_on', 'DESC');
```